# jquery masonry wordpress categories

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-masonry

So i have masonry set up it works, the categories work however they stay in the orginal position but when i select a category there maybe only one brick but it stays at the bottom I need the masonry to reload after the posts not in the selected category have been hidden. I have tryed various solutions not of which have worked for

1st solution not work

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
// This line tells the script to run after the page is loaded,
// As well as allows you to use the `$` function within the script
jQuery(function($) {  
$('#pincontainer').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.pin-gallery', 
});
});
</script>
```

this does work to an exstent but container wont centre and last li float bottom left of page even when theres loads of space
also tryed the below

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#container').masonry({
            $('#container').masonry({
   columnWidth: 320,
   itemSelector: '.brick',
     isFitWidth: true,
  }).imagesLoaded(function() {
   $('#container').masonry('reload');

  });
});

          $('#portfolio-filter').click(function() {

              $('#container ul li').eq(2)
                  .css({'visibility': 'hidden', 'display': 'none'})
                  .removeClass("brick masonry-brick");

              $('#container').masonry('reload');

          });


</script>
```

the masonry stoped working so the above could work but i dont know how javascipt/jquery works so I woulndt know if the code looked right

this is the code i have at the minute but doesnt reload the masonry/reoganise the items after category selected
    $(document).ready(function() {

```
  $('#container').masonry({
   columnWidth: 320,
   itemSelector: '.brick',
     isFitWidth: true,
  }).imagesLoaded(function() {
   $('#container').masonry('reload');

  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did all the punctuation keys in your keyboard stop working?

Comment: yeah but if you cant help I don't really see the point in commenting since it clearly explains the problem and the solutions attempted.